# V'yaazor v'yagen... and no amen

Tags: torah-service, amen, gabbai

On Shabbat, the gabbai calls the kohen to the Torah with the following formula:

> ויעזור ויגן ויושיע לכל החוסים בו ונאמר אמן. הכל הבו גודל...

I have never heard anyone say amen after the prompt. Why not?

Comment: Maybe because the gabbai doesn't pause to let them get an "amen" in edgewise? Of course, he probably doesn't because no one ever says "amen."

Comment: I say it. Should I not? Uh oh.

Comment: I've seen people say it.

Comment: I always say it and I always hear people say amen

Comment: Perhaps it's dependent on nusach or locality?

Comment: I also say it.  You need to daven at a minyan with more Mi Yodeyans.

Comment: @YEZ http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1625/759 http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1635/759

Comment: i usually say    .

Comment: People **should** say 'amen'. Most of the time, the gabbai either doesn't say it loud enough *or* he's speeding through it. Both scenarios are unfortunate.

Comment: I say it - along with a few during Rosh-Chodesh Benching that seem to be ignored.